# How can checkboxes be sorted (based on true-false status) in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I have a table I designed on a **'react-table'**. I want to sort according to the checkboxes I marked on my table. For example, when I press **column name**, the true ones should be listed first. I'll be happy if you can help me.

[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f30KE.png) (true values ​​should have been first or false values by choice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research, I learned that it can be done with sortType. We can sort the boolean values ​​by adding this code to the relevant column.

```
sortType: ((a, b, id) => {
          if (a.original[id] > b.original[id]) return -1; 
          if (b.original[id] > a.original[id]) return 1;
        }),
```

Answer (score 5):

The other solution works, but it's not necessary.

I got stuck with this as well, until I realized that one can set `sortType: 'basic'` (which is one of the built-in sorts of react-table) and it will sort the boolean column properly.

The reason that sorting a boolean column doesn't work out of the box is because the default sorting is set to `alphanumeric`.